# Define HTTP routes to serve only "internal" requests with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, saml-2.0, spring-saml

My question may seem kind of strange, but I'd like to better understand how Spring Security works.

I've a scenario as follows...

By using **Spring Security** and **Spring SAML**, I defined an entry point, some patterns and filters in order to properly manage *http* requests.

```
<!-- Secured pages -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint"
    use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/metadata" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/metadata/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/info" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/signup/sso" access="permitAll" />
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST"
        ref="metadataGeneratorFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"
        ref="samlFilter" />
</security:http>

<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**"
            filters="samlEntryPoint" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**"
            filters="samlLogoutFilter" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**"
            filters="metadataDisplayFilter" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**"
            filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**"
            filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**"
            filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" />
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**"
            filters="samlIDPDiscovery" />
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Then, I defined also an **IdP discovery service**:

```
<!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
<bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
    <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/sso/idpSelection" />
</bean>
```

At last, I implemented a **web-controller** to serve http requests to `/sso/idpSelection`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sso")
public class SSOController {
    // Logger
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SSOController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/idpSelection", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String idpSelection(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {           
        WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext());
        MetadataManager metadataManager = context.getBean("metadata", MetadataManager.class);
        Set<String> idps = metadataManager.getIDPEntityNames();
        for (String idp : idps)
            LOG.info("Configured Identity Provider for SSO: " + idp);
        model.addAttribute("idp", idps);
        return "sso/idpselection";
    }
}
```

When an anonymous user attempts to access protected pages, a filter redirect his request to `/saml/discovery` and thus the IdP discovery service calls the controller for `/sso/idpSelection`.

It's clear that the route `/sso/idpSelection` should be used only by the IdP Discovery Service, as *internal* resource.

Is there a way to deny direct-access requests (e.g. by browser) but allowing the route for *internal* processes at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAMLDiscovery makes a forward when sending users to the /sso/idpSelection. This means that you could programatically disallow users from accessing the page directly using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/idpSelection", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String idpSelection(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {  
   if (request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri") == null) {
       // Deny access
   }
   ...
}
```

The attribute "javax.servlet.forward.request_uri" is automatically set by container during call to requestDispatcher's forward method and therefore won't be present in direct requests. The feature is available since Servlet 2.4.